# Best way to visit N graph vertices with special constraints

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph.

```
Node | Adjacent nodes
[00] | 04 09 12 06 14 03 10
[01] | 13 08 10 06 05 11 02 14
[02] | 04 10 07 08 01
[03] | 14 12 10 11 13 00 09
[04] | 14 13 02 00 05 08
[05] | 07 04 01 10 08 06
[06] | 12 00 08 01 14 05
[07] | 13 05 02 09
[08] | 12 01 10 06 04 02 05 14
[09] | 00 07 10 03
[10] | 02 14 03 08 01 09 11 05 00
[11] | 14 03 12 01 10
[12] | 03 06 08 00 13 11
[13] | 07 01 04 14 03 12
[14] | 03 04 11 13 10 00 06 08 01
```

[image: Graph]

**Conditions:**

One can visit any available (unvisited) vertex (manual visit).
Manually visited vertex automatically visits adjacent vertices.

**Example:**

At the first step of the graph below I can start from any vertex.
I decided to manually visit vertex (7).
Vertex (7) automatically visits vertices (2), (5), (9), (13).
Vertices (2), (5), (7), (9), (13) are marked as visited and can't be used in subsequent manual selections.
Repeat the steps until no vertices are available for a manual visit.

As demonstrated in the example above, a vertex for the next manual visit was selected randomly. Depending on vertex connections, one can manually visit only N vertices, and the number N varies depending on what vertex is selected next.

For example, in the graph below I can visit only 4 vertices manually by randomly selecting unvisited vertices.

Manually (7), automatically (2), (5), (9), (13);
Manually (4), automatically (0), (8), (14);
Manually (6), automatically (1), (12);
Manually (3), automatically (10), (11);
Stop. No unvisited vertices are available for a manual visit.

Formal iterations:

```
Init
[00] | 04 09 12 06 14 03 10
[01] | 13 08 10 06 05 11 02 14
[02] | 04 10 07 08 01
[03] | 14 12 10 11 13 00 09
[04] | 14 13 02 00 05 08
[05] | 07 04 01 10 08 06
[06] | 12 00 08 01 14 05
[07] | 13 05 02 09
[08] | 12 01 10 06 04 02 05 14
[09] | 00 07 10 03
[10] | 02 14 03 08 01 09 11 05 00
[11] | 14 03 12 01 10
[12] | 03 06 08 00 13 11
[13] | 07 01 04 14 03 12
[14] | 03 04 11 13 10 00 06 08 01

Selected: 07, automatically: [13, 05, 02, 09]
[00] | 03 04 06 10 12 14
[01] | 06 08 10 11 14
[03] | 00 10 11 12 14
[04] | 00 08 14
[06] | 00 01 08 12 14
[08] | 01 04 06 10 12 14
[10] | 00 01 03 08 11 14
[11] | 01 03 10 12 14
[12] | 00 03 06 08 11
[14] | 00 01 03 04 06 08 10 11

Selected: 04, automatically: [00, 08, 14]
[01] | 06 10 11
[03] | 10 11 12
[06] | 01 12
[10] | 01 03 11
[11] | 01 03 10 12
[12] | 03 06 11

Selected: 06, automatically: [01, 12]
[03] | 10 11
[10] | 03 11
[11] | 03 10

Selected: 03, automatically: [10, 11]
Stop
```

**What is the best way (algorithms) to answer these questions:**

If I can manually visit 4 vertices for a random run, what would be the maximum number of vertices that I could visit manually ? Is it possible to calculate this amount in advance by a formula ?

Would it be possible to calculate by a formula in how many ways one can manually visit the N number of vertices ?

How to optimally traverse a graph to manually visit the maximum amount of vertices ?

Comment: So you are looking for a Maximum [Independent Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory))?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for a hint!